# Localstorage gets cleared on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to save my playlists in local storage. I've got 2 default playlists and an option to add one through a modal. The playlist I create gets added to localstorage fine, but when I refresh they created playlist(s) are gone and only the default values are still stored in localstorage. What am I doing wrong?

The state:

```
const [sidebarState, setSidebarState] = useState({
    currentPlaylist: 'home',
    modal: false,
    playlists: { home: new Set(), favorites: new Set() },
    succes: ''
  });
```

and the useEffect hooks:

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('MUSIC_LIBRARY_APP', JSON.stringify(sidebarState.playlists));
  }, [sidebarState.playlists]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('MUSIC_LIBRARY_APP');
    if (data !== null) setSidebarState({ playlists: JSON.parse(data) });
  }, []);
```

Comment: First ``useEffect`` should check and keep data if there is any data stored on ``localStorage`` before update with the ``useState`` default value

Comment: On the first useEffect call, you are setting localstorage with data from your state. Now that you have data in localstorage, remove default state and remove the setting storage on load from the initial component load from use effect